# Binding to an ObservableCollection of UserControls

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml

Simple Silverlight question: I have an ObservableCollection<MyObject> in my viewmodel. Every MyObject has a Label property. If I bind a ListBox to the collection and set DisplayMemberPath to Label, or set the ItemTemplate to a TextBlock that binds the Text property to Label, all works as expected.

If I change MyObject so it derives from a UserControl, the Label text no longer shows up in the ListBox; each item just shows up as a blank strip a few pixels tall. Why is this? There's obviously something I'm missing here about how different things get rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListBox determines that the set of items in its `ItemsSource` are already `UIElement` instances and therefore decides to use those elements directly as the content of the `ListBoxItem` elements it creates.

Comment: Thanks. It's this kind of thing that frustrates me about XAML - I can give it very specific instructions to render the content in a certain way and it completely ignores them!

Comment: nlawalker: Either they didn't anticipate this scenario or perhaps they felt the cost of working round this scenario wasn't woth the effort.  After all it is quite strange to take a set of UIElements and treat them as data